# How to obtain the local unbiased condition for an estimator from global unbiased condition?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, unbiased-estimator

A standard problem in classical statistics is to find a good estimator that minimizes a given cost function under certain conditions. Normally we want to require the estimator $\hat\theta$ to be unbiased in every possible value of unknown parameters, that is
$$
\mathrm{E}_{\boldsymbol{\theta }}^{(n)}\left[ \hat{\theta}\left( X^n \right) \right] :=\sum_{x^n\in \mathcal{X} ^n}{p_{\boldsymbol{\theta }}^{(n)}}\left( x^n \right) \hat{\theta}\left( x^n \right) =\theta 
$$
where $x^n$ is the experiment result for $n$ times. In eq(5) of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.02790#:%7E:text=In%20parameter%20estimation%2C%20nuisance%20parameters,estimating%20other%20parameters%20of%20interest.), the author states that we can get the following local unbiased condition by Taylor expanding the above conditions to be
$$
\begin{array}{c}
 \mathrm{E}_{\boldsymbol{\theta }}^{(n)}\left[ \hat{\theta}\left( X^n \right) \right] =\sum_{x^n\in \mathcal{X} ^n}{p_{\boldsymbol{\theta }}^{(n)}}\left( x^n \right) \hat{\theta}\left( x^n \right) =\theta ,\\
 \partial _{\theta}\mathrm{E}_{\boldsymbol{\theta }}^{(n)}\left[ \hat{\theta}\left( X^n \right) \right] =\sum_{x^n\in \mathcal{X} ^n}{\partial _{\theta}}p_{\boldsymbol{\theta }}^{(n)}\left( x^n \right) \hat{\theta}\left( x^n \right) =1,\\
\end{array}
$$
But I'm not sure how can we do the Taylor expansion to get the second set of restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work on *local unbiasedness* was done back in the 50s. The most prominent and accessible work $[\rm I]$ is due to Fraser.

First, understand the definition: $h(\mathbf x) $ is locally unbiased at $\boldsymbol\theta_0$ if

\begin{align}\mathbb E[h(\mathbf x) \mid \boldsymbol\theta_0]&=\boldsymbol\theta_0,\tag{LU-1}\label 2\\ \frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol\theta_0}\mathbb E[h(\mathbf x) \mid \boldsymbol\theta_0]&=\mathbf I. \tag{LU-2}\label 1\end{align}

A globally-unbiased estimator satisfies the conditions for every $\boldsymbol\theta_0.$
Implicit assumption is the basic regularity condition: the support should not depend on $\boldsymbol\theta$ at $\boldsymbol\theta_0$ and interchange of derivative and integral is valid.

For simplicity consider one-dimensional parameter $\theta.$ Then $h(\mathbf x) $ is unbiased *locally* at $\theta_0$ if $\eqref{2}, \eqref{1}$ hold. But this just implies $$\mathbb E[h(\mathbf x) \mid \theta]=\theta_0+(\theta-\theta_0)+o(\theta-\theta_0).$$

Can you now be able to connect to and show  your result?

By expanding the log-likelihood at nhood of $\theta_0, $ and using a minimal-sufficient statistic based on it, one can construct using the CR-bound a local-unbiased estimator.

---

### Reference:

$\rm [I]$ On Local Unbiased Estimation, *D. A. S. Fraser,* Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series B (Methodological), Vol. $26,$ No. $1,~ (1964),$ pp.$ 46-51.$

Answer (score 0):

The way that I understand how the local unbiased condition is obtained from the global unbiased condition can well be shown in the following picture
[image]

where the horizontal axis means the true value $\theta$ and the vertical axis means the expectation value of the estimator $\hat \theta$. The mean value of our estimator should be exactly the true value at the true value point($1/2$ in the picture) and the first derivative of the red curve should have the same slope as the blue one in the true value point.